# Capture the beginning of a string (empty string) as a match itself via regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
''.match(/^/)
// ['']

'ab'.match(/\w/g)
// ['a', 'b']

'ab'.match(/^|\w/g)
// ['', 'b']
```

As you can see, `^` is captured **instead** of `a` in the latest example, with the first match somehow being "the start of the string" but *not* "the starting character itself".

What regex would capture `['', 'a', 'b']` from the string `'ab'`?

Comment: Now I understand your dilemma. Works in PCRE, but in most other languages (JavaScript, Python, Go, etc.) it returns either the position or the character, but not both since the element at position `0` has already matched.

Comment: You can use `^(?=(\w)|)|\w`

Answer (score 2):

#### What's happening?

In PCRE `^|\w` matches both the start of line assertion `^` (empty string) and the word character `\w` (`a`).

In JavaScript, `^` satisfies a match at position `0` in the string, thus it moves onto position `1` (which matches `b`), skipping the match of `a` since that position has already been successfully matched.

I'd have to confirm, but it appears that most regex engines (JavaScript, Python, Go, etc.) only return one match per position. PCRE will return the results you seek for `^|\w` as it appears to return positional zero-length matches as well as the character matches.

---

#### Working regex

You can use the following pattern to match/capture the results you're looking for:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/P8jgcg/4) (look at match information on right)

```
^(?=(\w)|)|\w
```

---

#### Working code

The code below demonstrates how you would convert the results from the regex above into an array (using `exec` in a loop and then filtering the results to ensure we remove the capture group when it's `undefined`).

```js
const regex = /^(?=(\w)|)|\w/g;
const str = `ab`;
let matches=[];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    matches = matches.concat(m.filter(function(el){return typeof el !== 'undefined'}))
}

console.log(matches)
```

Or using `matchAll` as mentioned in comments below:

```js
const regex = /^(?=(\w)|)|\w/g;
const str = `ab`;
let matches=[];

for (const a of str.matchAll(regex) {
  matches = matches.concat(a.filter(function(el){return typeof el !== 'undefined'}))
}

console.log(matches)
```

And even shorter:

```js
x = [...'ab'.matchAll(/^(?=(\w)|)|\w/g)].flat().filter(n=>n!==undefined)
console.log(x)
```

Comment: This is a Javascript question and that doesn't return `['', 'a', 'b']` in Javascript: `'ab'.match(/^(?=(\w)|)|\w/g)` -> `['', 'b']`

Comment: @fregante I added script to show how to accomplish it. You just have to loop over exec and filter.

Comment: Also achievable via the new `.matchAll`: `for (const a of 'ab'.matchAll(/^(?=(\w)|)|\w/g)) {console.log(a)}` but sadly it needs further code to extract it as a single array, which defeats the purpose of using this shortcut to extract an empty string. If that's impossible in JS then I'll accept that

Comment: @fregante updated with matchAll method as alternative. `concat` merges and flattens the array to your specified output.

Comment: @ctwheels Out of curiosity, what is reason for the pipe in `(\w)|`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird In case the sentence has a non-word character at the beginning, I'm assuming the OP wants to match it: `.b` for example would match start of string and `b` - otherwise it would just match `b`. The lookahead is just a hack to match the first letter anyway. Making the lookahead optional no longer matches `a`, so made it an alternation.

Comment: Having all that code around the regex defeats the purpose; I was hoping to use `^` to have shorter code. It's not "a single regex" anymore, it's programming, so I ended up using `['', ...('ab'.match(/\w/g) || [])]`

Comment: @fregante I'm not sure what you mean by that. It's still regex that's getting you those values, that's how the regex engine is intended to work in JavaScript. We have to call `exec` or `matchAll` to get the groups (by design), we need to filter the results to remove `undefined` values when the capture group doesn't match anything (by design again - regex engine giving us capture group feedback), we need to `concat` the array results to get the exact output you specified. Regex isn't a code replacement, it's a parsing tool designed to be integrated into your codebase.

Comment: @fregante I added another example using `matchAll` - it's a one-liner and I think more concise than the other examples. Maybe this better suits your needs?